# TFS express access for remote users

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, source-control-explorer

I have a `TFS` express configured on my windows server. Is it possible to invite a remote user on his email address, so that he can connect to the server and access project collections? I had been through few similar SO posts, and tried to explore almost all parts of the admin panel, but could't found such feature.

*(I know this is available in case of visualstudio.com, but I need to invite a remote user to my locally hosted TFS)*.

**Question:** 
 - Is it even possible to allow remote user to access my TFS?
 - If so, how to authenticate him?

*Other Info:* TFS is perfectly configured, and is accessible remotely as http://xyz:8080/tfs

Comment: Suggest you to use vsts( https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-hans/team-services/) which is more suitable for your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. When TFS is installed on-premise it reads its users from the Windows Active directory and/or local Windows Server users.

When TFS is configured to be accessible remotely, like you say using an externally visible domain name, you need to register a Windows user either in Active Directory (preferred) or locally on the server.

To make your life easier, consider employing Visual Studio Team Services, the cloud service based offering that offers mostly the same services TFS does. It also provides 5 free users, doesn't need to be installed and maintained on a Windows Server, doesn't cost you a Windows Server license and allows you to invite people using their Microsoft Account/Windows Live ID.